# IUIAutomationElement to WinRT AutomationElement mapping in C#

Tags: .net, windows-runtime, com-interop, microsoft-ui-automation

I am trying to use [Microsoft UI Automation](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-uiautomation) Project.

What I understand so far after reading through the Functional Tests, that are part of Project, that IUIAutomationElement needs to be converted to AutomationElement, that is exposed as a WinRT interface.

I am trying it via C# where I am using IUIAutomationElement from Interop.UIAutomatonClient library and trying it to cast to WinRT AutomationElement.

The theory is based on the code from functional tests itself that casts IUIAutomationElement COM Pointer to winrt::AutomationElement

If my understanding is correct, then how could I achieve this?
A sample where I just try to get the GUI handle and get its IUIAutomationElement. Evidently, I cannot just use ImportElement function that expects AutomationElement as there is no explicit or implicit cast that exists.

'''

```
            var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("myprocess");
            var process = processes.FirstOrDefault(p => p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero);
            IUIAutomation automation = new CUIAutomation();

            IUIAutomationElement automationElement = automation.ElementFromHandle(process.Handle);

            AutomationRemoteOperation op = new AutomationRemoteOperation();
            op.ImportElement(automationElement);// error
```

'''

Comment: From C# and Visual Studio, just add a COM reference to `windows\system32\UIAutomationCore.dll` and off you go. You don't need anything else to program UI automation. Note you may have to set `Embed Interop Types` to `False` on this reference, depending on what you use from it.

Comment: thanks @SimonMourier. I use Interop version of UIA. Microsoft UI Automation project I mentioned in the query should help to reduce the inter process calls (example for an Element's properties) by batching them. I was trying to figure out way to leverage that in a C# project.

Comment: Ow, I missed that one. What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: There is a demo C# project in the solution itself, that is on 4.7.2. I am just trying with that.

Comment: Not sure it can be easily done with .NET Framework as you can't get a WinRT projected type from an IUnknown pointer. It does work with C# .NET 6 and C#/WinRT (but the Microsoft.UI.UIAutomation project must be reworked with C++/WinRT) and in this case the code can be: `var op = new AutomationRemoteOperation(); var unk = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(automationElement); var e = MarshalInterface<AutomationElement>.FromAbi(unk); op.ImportElement(e);` afaik there's no equivalent of MarshalInterface<T>.FromAbi with .NET Framework

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful and I am going to give it a try. I too had doubts about Framework, however, considering it is given as a default project, I presumed it to work with current Projections. I was also searching for equivalent of copy_from_abi in framework and could not find it myself.